# Can I ask yum to tell me what it would delete with a "yum remove" command

Tags: linux, yum

Is there a way to tell what yum would do *"but not do it"* for a given yum command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have specified `assumeyes` (`-y`) it should already do this.

See the following as an example:

```
# yum remove python-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, presto
Setting up Remove Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python-devel.x86_64 0:2.6.5-3.el6_0.2 set to be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

=================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                     Arch                                  Version                                         Repository                               Size
=================================================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 python-devel                                x86_64                                2.6.5-3.el6_0.2                                 @updates                                443 k

Transaction Summary
=================================================================================================================================================================================
Remove        1 Package(s)
Reinstall     0 Package(s)
Downgrade     0 Package(s)

Is this ok [y/N]:
```